# why nothing shows in live server using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Here is my code in html and js hope you can help**

```js
    import React from "react"
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
    import TopPart from "./TopPart"
    import BottomPart from "./BottomPart"
    import Footer from "./Footer"
    
    function App(){
    return(
    <div>
        <TopPart />
        <BottomPart />
        <Footer />
    </div>
    )
    }
    ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById("root"))
```

```html
//HTML
    
    <html>
    
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script src="./index.js"></script>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

**I am just starting with react and have no idea what should I fix to make it show something in live server**

> Blockquote

Comment: Are you getting any error in the console ?

Comment: no,nothing at all

Comment: do i need to use some script so it knows that I'm using react?

Comment: For react code, you can use codesandbox link or something, in order to replicate the issue.

Comment: Please provide more information. Did you use CRA to initialize your react-app ? Do you use live-server with the terminal ? vscode extension ?

Comment: i have used just npm create vite@latest

Answer (score 0):

If you either installed react or you just did npx, usually on your terminal you can run:

```
npm start
```

and this will prompt you / redirect you to your computer's default browser and open a window with the url "localhost:5005".
Hope this helps you!

Comment: I just ran npm create vite@latest before

Comment: @TeaAleksov if you are using Vite, then you can run the command:
```
npm run dev 
```
after that, on your terminal it will show the link to the local environment where it will show everything you made so far :)